# The administrative limit for this request was exceeded

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I have a command to wipe out our Active Directory (AD) structure and rebuild it for testing.
The command will also be used in Prod to do the initial setup of the AD structure.

On our dev sandbox AD server it works fine. In the QA AD server I get the error

> The administrative limit for this request was exceeded.

Googling has indicated I either need to call the delete method in a loop, on that exception, or
get the admins to change a setting.

What setting it is that needs changing and if there is a hardcoded maximum?

They are different active directories. This one is Server 2008 R2, the other is Server 2003.

Answer (score 2):

The setting is one that limits how many objects you can fetch in one go. Microsoft changed behavior between Active Directory in 2003 and 2008. In 2003 you could set it really high and it would honor it. In 2008 you can set it really high, but it just puts an arbitrary cap on it. With 40K objects in our AD tree, in 2003 you could pull them all from a single LDAP command, when we went to 2008 (same AD setting, mind) we were limited to 10,000 objects. This was a hard limit

The only way around it was to configure the LDAP *client* to support paged search mode. When you connect to the LDAP server you tell it you'll accept 'pages' of a specific number. When you make queries, your replies are sent in chunks no larger than what you specified as your max page-size. This reduces load on the LDAP servers by quite a bit, and is why Microsoft put an arbitrary maximum (10K) on it.